# SQL Query to Group Columns

Tags: sql, group-by, db2

I am running a query which I want to only show distinct customers from.

At the current time I am receiving records which have multiple records for example 3 records for Item `A0003`. I want to only return the last record in the sequence.

My code:

```
select OJCUNO AS Item,OJPRRF as code,OJFVDT as From Date, OJLVDT as To Date
from M3FDBPRD.OPRICH 
WHERE
   OJCUNO in ( Select max(OJCUNO) FROM OPRICH group by OJCUNO )
```

Data Sample:

```
Item        Code    From Date       To Date
A0007       AD      20030301        20161231
A0008       AF      20030301        20161231
A0009       AL      20030301        20121229
A0009       AL      20030301        20121231
```

Expected Result:

```
Item        Code    From Date       To Date
A0007       AD      20030301        20161231
A0008       AF      20030301        20161231
A0009       AL      20030301        20121231
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Using DB2 database

Comment: It is not clear from your sample what you want to group on, item is unique in all rows and the sql query doesn't match the sample data. Improve your input and add expected output

Comment: The data sample you have shown in the question contains the following columns: `Item    ,    Code   , From Date     ,  To Date`, while the query has these columns: `OJCUNO AS CUSTOMER,OJPRRF,OJFVDT,OJLVDT `. These two seems to be completely unrelated. Please explain this discrepancy, because your question is unclear.

Comment: Hi guys, please see my code edits and expected results.

Comment: Try editing expected result, my friend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `row_number()`:

```
select OJCUNO AS Item, OJPRRF as code ,OJFVDT as FromDate, OJLVDT as ToDate
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ojcuno order OJPRRF desc, OJLVDT desc) as seqnum
      from M3FDBPRD.OPRICH o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

Your approach, using a correlated subquery would work if you used the right columns:

```
select OJCUNO AS Item,OJPRRF as code, OJFVDT as FromDate, OJLVDT as ToDate
from M3FDBPRD.OPRICH 
where OJLVDT in ( Select max(OJLVDT) from OPRICH group by OJCUNO );
```

Comment: Your 2-nd query provides wrong results on a slightly different input data (multiple OJLVDT values for some particular OJCUNO are among max OJLVDT for some another OJCUNO). The query should look like below. `with OPRICH (OJCUNO, OJPRR, OJFVDT , OJLVDT) as (values
  ('A0007', 'AD', 20030301, 20161231)
, ('A0008', 'AF', 20030301, 20161231)
, ('A0009', 'AL', 20030301, 20161231)
, ('A0009', 'AL', 20030301, 20171231)
)
select t.* from OPRICH t
join (select OJCUNO, max(OJLVDT) OJLVDT from OPRICH group by OJCUNO) g on g.OJCUNO=t.OJCUNO and t.OJLVDT=g.OJLVDT;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just having a stab here because I don't have access to a DB2 database to test on, but:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
select OJCUNO AS Item,
OJPRRF as code,
OJFVDT as From Date,
OJLVDT as To Date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OJCUNO, OJPRRF ORDER BY OJFVDT DESC, OJLVDT DESC) AS RNum
from M3FDBPRD.OPRICH 
WHERE
   OJCUNO in ( Select max(OJCUNO) FROM OPRICH group by OJCUNO )
) a
WHERE a.RNum = 1
```

Comment: Does not like the . after To date. Can you advise?